# A "counterbalancing" trigonometric sum inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

Is it true that
$$s_{n,k}:=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} r_{n,k,j}  
<0$$
for all natural $n\ge2$ and all natural $k\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$,
where
$$\text{$r_{n,k,j}:=\frac{x_{n,2j}}{y_{n,k,j}\;y_{n,k+1,j}},\quad$
$x_{n,j}:=\sin^2\frac{\pi  j}{2 n},\quad$ and $\quad y_{n,k,j}:=2x_{n,j}-x_{n,k-1}-x_{n,k}$?}$$

This question was motivated by [this previous one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/436409/36721).

---

One may note here that for each natural $n\ge2$ and each natural $k\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ we have $r_{n,k,k}<0$, whereas  $r_{n,k,j}>0$ for all $j\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}\setminus\{k\}$ – but the only negative summand $r_{n,k,k}$ in the sum $\sum_{j=1}^n r_{n,k,j}$ seems to more than counterbalance the other, positive summands $r_{n,k,j}$ with $j\ne k$. For instance, here are approximate values of $r_{10,4,j}$ for $j\in\{1,\dots,10-1\}$:
$$0.24, 1.50, 11.00, -42.00, 14.00, 2.60, 0.85, 0.29, 0.06.$$

However, the counterbalancing effect seems somewhat delicate, as (at least for $k\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ far enough from $1$ and $n-1$) the ratio of the sum $s_{n,k}$ to $r_{n,k,k}$ seems to be decreasing  to $0$ as $n$ increases to $\infty$.

Comment: Did you write the MathJax code the way you did for the purpose of preventing line breaks in the line after the word "where"?

Comment: what is the motivation for this? Why do you think the sum is negative in general?

Comment: @MichaelHardy : This just seems a fast way to convert inline formulas to a displayed one.

Comment: @Conrad : I have added a line on the motivation. The evidence for the conjecture is so far only numerical.

Comment: Excellent- was curious why one considers the fairly complicated expressions above

Comment: @Conrad : Thank you for your comments.